# checkbox is not giving correct value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a checkbox in form array. I have applied limit in checkbox selection that not more than 2 checkbox are selected.

```html
         <input type="checkbox"  formControlName="Viewable" class="form-control checkbox"
                        (change)="selectViewable($event)" />
```

on selecting 3rd checkbox, it is giving different value in event and `event.target.checked`. Any recommendation what i am missing.?? Why is it giving different values

```
   selectViewable(event){
     console.log(event)
      console.log(event.target.checked)

    if (event.target.checked === true){
      if(this.counter < 2){
        this.counter++
      } else{
         event.target.checked = false;
         this.toastrService.info("You cannot select viewable more than 2");
      }
    } else if(this.counter>0){
      
      this.counter--;
    }
    else{
      event.target.checked = false;
    }
  }


here is my stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbfpfg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
```

Comment: a stackblitz example will be helpful

Comment: what is the value of 'counter' ??

Comment: counter is set to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the value of the form manually to ensure that it matches. In your html

```
<form [formGroup]='myForm'>
  <ng-container formArrayName='myFormArray'>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of myFormArray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]='i'>
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="Viewable" class="form-control checkbox" (change)="selectViewable(i, $event)" />
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

</form>
```

In your TS

```
  selectViewable(i, event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.target.checked);

    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      if (this.counter < 2) {
        this.counter++;
      } else {
        event.target.checked = false;
        this.toastrService.info('You cannot select viewable more than 2');

        this.myFormArray
          .at(i)
          .get('Viewable')
          .setValue(false);
      }
    } else if (this.counter > 0) {
      this.counter--;
    } else {
      event.target.checked = false;
    }
  }
```

**[Sample Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p79fwt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

NB: You do not need to keep track of the number of checked items as the form array has all this info. Below will also work

```
  selectViewable(i) {
    const count = this.myFormArray.value.filter(({ Viewable }) => Viewable)
      .length;
    if (count > 2) {
      const control = this.myFormArray.at(i).get('Viewable');
      this.toastrService.info('You cannot select viewable more than 2');
      control.setValue(false);
    }
  }
```

And in your html no need to pass the event

```html
(change)="selectViewable(i)"
```

[**See Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e1hpqu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)